# Set date format dd/mm/yyyy in SQL table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable

I want to save the dates in my database in the dd/mm/yyyy format, because I want to import the table that contains them in a JTable (Java SE) and I want to display them in this format. Is it possible to directly save the date on my database in this format or I must do it in another way? My DB is write in SQL and I use MySQL.

Comment: I suggest you to save the date with the specific Date type in mysql. Let java format the date.

Comment: It's best to separate storage from presentation.  The database will stores the dates as it needs to.  Your front end is the best place to worry about the format.

Comment: Thanks, now I try it.

Answer (score 3):

Date are dates. It doesn't exists a format for dates.

What you can obtain is a string with a particular format from the date.

Note that the format probably is not `dd/mm/yyyy` but `dd/MM/yyyy` because `mm` is for minutes, not for months.

So basically you have two possibilities:

- Save dates as Date and retrieve them as string with the requested format
- Convert dates to strings and save them as formatted strings (VARCHAR for example)

To convert a Date to a String in MySql you can use the function [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

If you like to convert them in java you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I think it's better for me to use the SimpleDateFormat. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to save the date in the specified format but yes you can set the type of that field as String (in MySql varchar) and you can save whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, 
or else you have to use VARCHAR or CHAR, but thats not recommended.

save the date in DATE datatype with format yyyy-mm-dd.
don't mess with it.

When you fetch the records, use DATE_FORMAT function to convert it into your format. (if you use MySQL)

like

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

in your case

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(< your_date_field >, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT function to change the format of a date in MySQL.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d/%m/%Y')
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%d/%m/%Y') # FROM tablename
```

Refer to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) for more details.